# Eclipse Californium CoAP wildcard as url path

Tags: java, eclipse, url, iot, californium

I'm working on a CoAP app using Eclipse Californium that will declare explicitly only the root resource path, and the rest of the resources should be served and resolved through a wildcard `/root/*` just like on REST APIs or servlets.

Is there any way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I managed to do it.

So after a few hours of digging on their Source code here is what ended up doing.

Note that it works but it's only to show how it could be done, it's still a work on progress (I did this in 3h) as I removed some code like observer etc..

As soon as I have some time, I'll digg onto the Californium Api more and make this generic and optimized I'll create a Github project and link it here.

## 1 : Create a model class

```
public class ProxyRes {

    public  CoapResource coapRes;
    public  String  path;

    public ProxyRes () {
    }

    public CoapResource getCoapRes () {
        return coapRes;
    }

    public void setCoapRes (CoapResource coapRes) {
        this.coapRes = coapRes;
    }

    public String getPath () {
        return path;
    }

    public void setPath (String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```

## 2 : Create an abstract CoapResource that should inject the Wildcards list

```
public abstract class AbstractResource extends CoapResource {

    private LinkedList<String> wildcards;

    protected AbstractResource (String name) {
        super (name);
    }

    protected AbstractResource (String name, boolean visible) {
        super (name, visible);
    }

    public LinkedList<String> getWildcards () {
        return wildcards;
    }

    public void setWildcards (LinkedList<String> wildcards) {
        this.wildcards = wildcards;
    }
}
```

## 3 : Create a Temperature Resource extending AbstractResource

```
public class TemperatureResource extends AbstractResource {

    public TemperatureResource () {
        super (ResourceSpecs.House.Sensors.Temperature);

        getAttributes ().setTitle ("Temperature resource !");
    }

    @Override
    public void handleGET (CoapExchange exchange) {
        String response = "The temperature";
        if (getWildcard () != null) {
            response += " of the " + getWildcard ().get (0) + " on the " + getWildcard ().get (1);
        }
        response += " is : 25 degree C";

        exchange.respond (response);
    }
}
```

## 4 : Create a resources directory on the root of my eclipse project, with json conf files of my resources

```
{
    "verb": "get",
    "endpoint": "/houses/*/rooms/*/sensors/temperature",

    "class": "com.wild.coap.resources.TemperatureResource"
}
```

## 5 : Create a Resources Loader (class that will load the specs definition of the resources and instantiate them independently instead of creating a Tree on the server)

```
public class ResourcesLoader {

    private final static String Path = new File (".").getAbsolutePath () + File.separator + "resources";

    private List<ProxyRes>  resourcesList;

    public ResourcesLoader () throws Exception {
        resourcesList   = new ArrayList<ProxyRes> ();

        File resources  = new File (Path);
        for (String resName : resources.list ()) {
            File resFile    = new File (resources, resName);
            InputStream is  = new FileInputStream (resFile);
            JsonObject o    = new JsonObject (is);

            resourcesArr.add (o);
            resourcesList.add (buildObject (o));
        }
    }

    private ProxyRes buildObject (JsonObject o) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        ProxyRes r = new ProxyRes ();
        r.setPath (o.getString ("endpoint"));

        Class<?> clazz  = Class.forName (o.getString ("class"));
        CoapResource coapRes = (CoapResource)clazz.newInstance ();
        r.setCoapRes (coapRes);

        return r;
    }

    public List<ProxyRes> getResourcesList () {
        return resourcesList;
    }
}
```

## 6 : Create a Custom MessageDelieverer

```
public class DynamicMessageDeliverer implements MessageDeliverer {

    private final List<ProxyRes>    resources;

    public DynamicMessageDeliverer (List<ProxyRes> resources) {
        this.resources  = resources;
    }

    public void deliverRequest (final Exchange exchange) {
        Request request         = exchange.getRequest ();
        List<String> path       = request.getOptions ().getUriPath ();

        final Resource resource = registerResources (path);     
        if (resource != null) {
            executeResource (exchange, resource);           
        } else {
            exchange.sendResponse (new Response (ResponseCode.NOT_FOUND));
            throw new RuntimeException ("Did not find resource " + path.toString() + " requested by " + request.getSource()+":"+request.getSourcePort());
        }
    }

    private void executeResource (final Exchange exchange, final Resource resource) {
        // Get the executor and let it process the request
        Executor executor = resource.getExecutor ();
        if (executor != null) {
            exchange.setCustomExecutor ();
            executor.execute (new Runnable () {

                public void run () {
                    resource.handleRequest (exchange);
                } 
            });
        } else {
            resource.handleRequest (exchange);
        }
    }

    private Resource registerResources (List<String> list) {
        LinkedList<String> path         = new LinkedList<String> (list);
        String flatRequestedEndpoint    = Arrays.toString (path.toArray ());
        LinkedList<String> wildcards    = new LinkedList <String> ();
        ProxyRes retainedResource       = null;

        for (ProxyRes proxyRes : resources) {
            String[] res = proxyRes.getPath ().replaceFirst ("/", "").split ("/");

            int length = res.length;
            if (length != path.size ()) {
                continue;
            }

            String flatResEndpoint = Arrays.toString (res);
            if (flatResEndpoint.equals (flatRequestedEndpoint)) {
                retainedResource = proxyRes;
                break;
            }

            boolean match = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i ++) {
                String str = res[i];
                if (str.equals ("*")) {
                    wildcards.add (path.get (i));
                    continue;
                }

                if (!str.equals (path.get (i))) {
                    match = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!match) {
                wildcards.clear ();
                continue;
            }

            retainedResource = proxyRes;
            break;
        }

        if (retainedResource == null) {
            return null;
        }

        ((AbstractResource)retainedResource.getCoapRes ()).setWildcard (wildcards);
        return retainedResource.getCoapRes ();
    }

    public void deliverResponse (Exchange exchange, Response response) {
        if (response == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if (exchange == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        if (exchange.getRequest() == null) throw new NullPointerException();
        exchange.getRequest().setResponse(response);
        Request request         = exchange.getRequest ();
        List<String> path       = request.getOptions ().getUriPath ();
        System.out.println ("Path retrieved : " + Arrays.toString (path.toArray ()));
    }
}
```

## 7 : Create the Server

```
public class WildCoapServer extends CoapServer {

    private static final int COAP_PORT = NetworkConfig.getStandard  ().getInt  (NetworkConfig.Keys.COAP_PORT);

    public WildCoapServer () throws Exception {

        // add endpoints on all IP addresses
        addEndpoints ();

        ResourcesLoader resLoader   = new ResourcesLoader ();
        List<ProxyRes> resources    = resLoader.getResourcesList ();

        setMessageDeliverer (new DynamicMessageDeliverer (resources));
    }

    @Override
    protected Resource createRoot () {
        return new WildRootResource ();
    }

    // Add individual endpoints listening on default CoAP port on all IPv4 addresses of all network interfaces.
    private void addEndpoints () {
        for (InetAddress addr : EndpointManager.getEndpointManager ().getNetworkInterfaces ()) {
            // only binds to IPv4 addresses and localhost
            if (addr instanceof Inet4Address || addr.isLoopbackAddress ()) {
                InetSocketAddress bindToAddress = new InetSocketAddress (addr, COAP_PORT);
                addEndpoint (new CoapEndpoint (bindToAddress));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## 8 : Start the server

```
public class Main {

    public static void main (String[] args) {

        try {
            WildCoapServer server = new WildCoapServer ();
            server.start ();
        } catch  (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException (e.getMessage (), e);
        }
    }
}
```

## 9 : Consume the Temperature resource from a client

```
public class Client {

    public static void main  (String[] args) {

        URI uri = null;
        try {
            uri = new URI ("coap://192.168.200.1:5683/houses/house1/rooms/kitchen/sensors/temperature");
        } catch  (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException (e.getMessage (), e);
        }

        CoapClient client       = new CoapClient (uri);

        CoapResponse response   = client.get ();

        if (response != null) {

            System.out.println (response.getCode ());
            System.out.println (response.getOptions ());
            System.out.println (response.getResponseText ());

            System.out.println ("\nADVANCED\n");
            // access advanced API with access to more details through .advanced ()
            System.out.println (Utils.prettyPrint (response));

        } else {
            System.out.println ("No response received.");
        }       
    }
}
```

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Did you manage to get a github repository? Can you share?

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution for this problem.

```
CoapResource wildcard = new CoapResource("*") {

    @Override
    public void handleGET(CoapExchange exchange) {
        ...
    }
};

CoapResource root = new CoapResource("root") {
    @Override
    public Resource getChild(String name) {
        return wildcard;
    }
};
```