# Dynamic uri on Californium

Tags: java, eclipse, californium

I have been trying to create a coap server in java using eclipse californium and I am facing some difficulties because what I need is to create a dynamic resource every time the client does a get request like: Client client = "coap://myhostname:port/dynamic_part/001". In this example what all devices have in common is that the only thing that they normally change is the dynamic part.
Thank you for every kind of help and suggestions in advanced.

I tried this method with wildcard in reverse way for this problem but didn't work(in this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310810/eclipse-californium-coap-wildcard-as-url-path](https://stackoverflow.com))

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "dynamic_part" as first element isn't that easy. If "coap://myhostname:port/dev/dynamic_part/001" works as well, the solution isn't too complicated.

1. Create the "dev" Resource using a special [getChild()](https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium/blob/main/demo-apps/cf-simplefile-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/examples/SimpleFileServer.java#L213-L220).
2. Access the URI-path using [getUriPathString()](https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium/blob/main/demo-apps/cf-simplefile-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/californium/examples/SimpleFileServer.java#L246) in handleGET of that Resource.

The URI-path will contain "dev/dynamic_part/...". If you want the path as list, use "getUriPath()". With that path, fetch the specific data you want to return as response. The sample use the URI-path to load a file, maybe that helps to understand, how it works.